# JAAS custom LoginModule

Tags: java, rest, ejb, jaas

I'm trying to write my costum LoginModule to be used in my REST service with Basic authorization. For this I made following:

1. I wrote my own LoginModule that is called QuarkLoginModule.
2. Added following snippet to web.xml:

   ```
   <security-role>
       <role-name>researcher</role-name>
   </security-role>
   <security-constraint>
       <display-name>SecurityConstraint</display-name>
       <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>Schedule</web-resource-name>
           <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
       </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint>
           <role-name>researcher</role-name>
       </auth-constraint>
       <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
       </user-data-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
   <login-config>
       <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
       <realm-name>quark</realm-name>
   </login-config>
   ```
3. Created file in /ejb/src/main/resources/META-INF/login.config with following contents:

   ```
   quark {
   edu.quark.auth.QuarkLoginModule required debug=true;
   }
   ```
4. Added following to JBoss runtime configuration to VM arguments section:

   ```
   "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/desertfox/Dresden/cbse/quark/ams-quark-1/ejb/src/main/resources/META-INF/login.config"
   ```
5. Added following snippet to standalone.xml:

   ```
   <security-domain name="quark" cache-type="default">
       <authentication>
           <login-module code="edu.quark.auth.QuarkLoginModule" flag="sufficient">
               <module-option name="roles" value="researcher"/>
               <module-option name="realm" value="quark"/>
           </login-module>                           
       </authentication>                                 
   </security-domain>
   ```

But instead of calling my LoginModule I receive a error message about wrong name/password all the time. And I get following exception:

```
02:43:44,825 ERROR [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Password Incorrect/Password Required
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:270) [picketbox-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule.login(UsersRolesLoginModule.java:155) [picketbox-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:449) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:383) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:371) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:160) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:214) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:180) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:455) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
```

As I can see, instead of my module, some default one is called `UsersRolesLoginModule`.

Could you tell me, please, what else could I try?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not setting the correct security domain "quark"? This can be done using a jboss-web.xml or using the `org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.SecurityDomain` annotation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_6_0.xsd"
           version="7.1">
    <context-root>/ctxroot</context-root>
    <security-domain>quark</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```